# Java Arrrays.asList issue

Tags: java, arrays, list, collections

I have tried to use Arrays.asList() method on a character array,something like below,

```
char[] array = "programming".toCharArray();
for (Character li : Arrays.asList(array)) {
  System.out.println(li);
}
```

But there was a compile time error.
Here Array.asList is returning me a Array of character arrays like below

```
for (char[] li : Arrays.asList(array)) {
    System.out.println(li);
}
```

What i know is, Arrays.asList() method converts each element of the array into an element in List .
But whats going on here?
can anybody help me in understanding this ?

Comment: "there was a compile time error": what error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Arrays.asList()` converts each reference type element to an element in the list. So if you pass an array of primitives, you'll get a list that contains a single element whose type is the type of the array you passed to it.

If you pass a `Character[]` array instead of a `char[]` array, you'll get a `List<Character>` containing all the elements of the input array as individual elements.

The signature of Arrays.asList is - `public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a)`. Since a generic type parameter must be a reference type, passing a primitive array is treated as if you passed a single element (whose type is the array type), which will result in a List having a single array element.

Comment: But i get a compile time error ,when i try to do this..i am shocked to see that!!   I mean ,when i do for (char li : Arrays.asList(array)) { ... }

Comment: @ravinderreddy You got a compilation error because calling `Arrays.asList` on a `char[]` productes a `List<char[]>`, not a `List<Character>`.